# How can i focus last append value in a textview/ scrollview

Tags: java, android

I trying to focus the last append value in the text box. But unfortunately i cant able to bring it up. Can you please help me to solve this.

```
<RelativeLayout
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="115dp"
android:orientation="vertical" >
<ScrollView android:id="@+id/ScrollView01"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="165dp"
    android:background="#FFFFFF" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvHistory"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:text=""
        android:textColor="#000000" />
</ScrollView>
```

Scroll view  and append is working correctly. But i want to focus last append value with a color

```
tvHistory.append(tvInput.getText()+"\n");
```

Comment: Please respond to my question.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it with just one TextView, because you can't have more than one color for a single TextView.

You might consider doing the following:

```
<ScrollView android:id="@+id/ScrollView01"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="165dp"
    android:background="#FFFFFF" >
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"  >
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvHistory"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#000000" />          
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvHighlight"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="some_other_color" />
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Now each time you want to append a new value, you do the following:

```
tvHistory.append(tvHighlight.getText().toString());
tvHighlight.setText(value);
```

Comment: Hi Benito,Thanks for your reply. Am doing a calculator apps. Whenever i click the equal button the value is appending on the history text view.I completed the scroll view and appending functionalists. Its appending below the previous value. I need it either the value appending above the previous value or focus last append with or without color.

Answer (score 0):

In Android you can style portions of a TextView by using a Spannable.http://developer.android.com/resources/faq/commontasks.html#selectingtext

```
int len = tvHistory.getText().length();
tvHistory.setText(tvHistory.getText() + tvInput.getText()+"\n", TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE);
Spannable str = tvHistory.getText();

// Create our span sections, and assign a format to each.
str.setSpan(new BackgroundColorSpan(0xFFFFFF00), len, str.length() - 1, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
```

Comment: Hi Flo,Thanks for your reply. Am doing a calculator apps. Whenever i click the equal button the value is appending on the history text view.I completed the scroll view and appending functionalists. Its appending below the previous value. I need it either the value appending above the previous value or focus last append with or without color.